# Delete record when value is integer

Tags: mysql

I have table which is "contaminated" with some unwanted values. There are integers and floats in column [score], and i wanna delete every record with integer in column [score]

Is there any function which allows me to do something like that:

```
delete from table where score like [integer]
```

Comment: What is the column definition of `score`, and what example values does it contain?  (When you say it has integers and floats, do you mean a textual representation of those in decimal notation?)  Also, is the database really mysql as tagged?  _[Bracketed identifiers]_ typically indicate MSSQL.

Comment: Column type is varchar. It's a big mistake, but table is small and not stores sensitive data (I wanna recover data from my earliest project when I'm really beginner). Example values: (10 , 1.235 , 2.256 , 4 , 6.548). I use [brackets] unfortunately, of course it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably work: `delete from table where score not like '%.%'`

Assuming all your "integers" are true integers and not "1.0...0"